# Is there a convention for showing overridden methods in UML static class diagrams?

Tags: inheritance, uml, overriding

If class `Human` inherits some methods from superclass `Mammal` unchanged (such as `laysEggs: () -> false`) and overrides other methods (such as `postsToStackOverflow : () -> true`), is there any difference between how the different methods are indicated in portion of the UML static class diagram for `Human`?  For example, are only the overridden methods shown in the box for `Human`, or are both shown, with some annotation for the overridden methods?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Now there is. Some anonymous got me to dig into the [2.5.1. specs](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF). On p. 102 it says

> Members that are inherited by a Classifier may be shown on a diagram of that Classifier by prepending a caret ’^’ symbol to the textual representation that would be shown if the member were not inherited. Thus the notation for an inherited Property is defined like this:
>
> `<inherited-property> ::= ’^’ <property>`
>
> where `<property>` is specified in 9.5.4.
>
> Similarly, the notation for an inherited Connector is defined like this:
>
> `<inherited-connector> ::= ’^’ <connector>`
>
> where `<connector>` is specified in 11.2.4.
>
> Analogous notations may be used for all NamedElements that are inheritedMembers of a Classifier to indicate that they are inherited.
>
> Inherited members may also be shown in a lighter color to help distinguish them from non-inherited members. A conforming implementation does not need to provide this option.

Since it applies for NamedElements it can be used for attributes and operations as well.

The specs itself does not (yet) make much use of the caret notation except  for figure 9.11 on p. 115 and figure 10.9 on p. 173.

---

In the specs for 2.5 and before the answer was: No, there isn't. You can only tell that a method is overridden by inspecting the methods of the class from which is inherited.

Answer (score 22):

See @qwerty_so answer for more up to date spec. The notation I propose below comes from outdated diagramming textbooks and college instruction from before 2008.

Though not specified in the UML standard, following is a notation understood to indicate when one function overrides another:

```
+ toString() : String <<override>>
```

Comment: please note that <<override>> is not define in UML specification document, so to use, normally you should define a profile or used an already existing profile which defines this stereotype.

Comment: Are profiles defined in the UML standard or would this be a feature of diagramming software? @granier

Comment: Profiles are defined in the UML spec (quite extensively). There is a bit of freedom they let the SW developers to render stereotypes. But basically it's fully described.

Comment: On. p 260 of UML 2.5 it is stated: _the name of the Stereotype is shown within a pair of guillemets above or before the name of the model element_ So the above is incorrect (besides the fact that the stereotype must belong to some profile).

Answer (score 9):

I duplicate method declaration, if I want to show that inherited class will override it, in other case just omit declaration.

Comment: Indeed, this is what UML calls an implicit redefinition (override): "Feature redefinitions may either be explicitly notated with the use of a {redefines <x>} (...) on the Feature or implicitly by having a Feature which cannot be distinguished (...) from another Feature in one of the owning Classifier’s more general Classifiers"