# How to get all overridden operations/attributes in a model?

Tags: java, eclipse, uml

In Java, suppose I have a UML model in eclipse (org.eclipse.uml2.uml) and want to retrieve all the overridden attributes and methods from all classifiers, how do I do that?

I can get all attributes and methods from a classifier, with .getAllAttributes() and .getAllOperations(), but I only want to get those, which override methods/attributes from parent classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (simply). The only way is to compare the attribute/operation names from class and superclass and pinpoint the duplicate ones.

See also [Is there a convention for showing overridden methods in UML static class diagrams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930476/is-there-a-convention-for-showing-overridden-methods-in-uml-static-class-diagram/28932482#28932482)

Comment: Could we assume that the overridden Attribute/Operation redefine other Attribute/Operation. In that case, maybe that the getRedefinedElement() should do the job!?

Comment: Hmm. If the Eclipse API offers such an operation. Just post it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your model was created but UML defines redefinedAttribute and redefinedOperation associations which can be used to model overridden Properties and Operations. In such case/model, you should be able to access to overridden Operation by using .getRedefinedOperation()...

[image]